# seaborn: adjust transparency of box around legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm drawing a scatterplot with seaborn. Around the legend is a box, which covers up the plot behind it. Can I remove this box and keep only the text inside it ?

Here is sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["x"] = [0, 0, 1, 1]
df["y"] = [1, 0, 1, 0]
df["group"] = list("abcd")

plt.figure()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="group")

leg = plt.legend(loc=[-0.02,0.5])
#remove border of box
#leg.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.0)

plt.show()
```

This plots:

[image: scatterplot]

The title of the legend and the text inside doesn't cover any of the scatterplot. But the half-transparent background box around it, does. Can I make this box so transparent that it disappears entirely ?

Answer (score 3):

See the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html#matplotlib-pyplot-legend). I think you are looking for

```
leg = plt.legend(loc=[-0.02,0.5], frameon=False)
```

but there are plenty of other options to change the appearance of the legend available.